# How come JLabel doesn't show underscore character?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

For some reason JLabel doesn't show underscore symbol.  Is there anything in particular I have to do for enabling such behavior?

Doesn't work in Windows, Linux, MacOS with Java 1.6.x

Comment: works on my machine, can you post the code you are trying to accomplish this with?

Comment: are you meaning `underscore character "_"` or "$"

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I used to see if this worked. Try running this on your machine.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestUnderscore 
{
  // Test routine.
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Test_Underscore$$"));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(450, 450);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does not work for me on Linux. Same issue for highlighted text in JTextArea. If line1 and line 2 contain underscores and both are highlighted, underscores in line 1 are not visible but underscores in line2 are. Changing alpha values of highlight color did not fix problem.

Found a fix - change the font. Both worked when I used Verdana 12pt.

Comment: I use Verdana 12pt too.  My problem was the height of the element vs. height of the font.  Properly adjusting (i.e. increasing) with height resolved the problem for me!